# Word of Binding with a Reach Weapon

Tags: dnd-4e, runepriest, reach

My Runepriest has the *Word of Binding* power, and is using a massive magic hammer with a reach 2. The weapon itself isn't in the book, but the concept is the same as a spear or polearm. My DM just decided to give it reach 2 since it was described as having a 7 ft. handle.

The *Word of Binding* power states:

> **Melee Weapon**
>
> **Hit:** Strength modifier damage, and the target is immobi­lized until the end of your next turn or until you aren't adjacent to it.

If I were to use this power while standing 2 squares away, and were to hit him with my hammer, would he be immobilised? Or to restate the question: If I was never adjacent to the target, does the target become immobilized, and stay immobilized as long as he is within reach of my weapon? Or would the power fail as soon as it started? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The target would become immobilized from the power, and then immediately lose the immobilized condition again because you are not adjacent to it.

So effectively the target would not be immobilized, although any effects that trigger off of "a creature becomes immobilized" would go off.